# Synonymes de "la deuxième guerre mondiale" ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Est-ce qu'il y a des synonymes pour le terme "la deuxième guerre mondiale" ?

Pour la première guerre mondiale, il existe aussi "la grande guerre" et "la guerre de 14-18". Est-ce que des termes similaires existent pour la deuxième guerre mondiale ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En France, quand on dit *la guerre* sans autre précision, il s'agit de la deuxième guerre mondiale (avant la guerre, pendant la guerre, après la guerre, après-guerre, etc.)

On peut aussi entendre *la guerre de 40* (mais il s'agit alors de l'offensive allemande vers la France, pas de la guerre mondiale) ou *la guerre 39-45* (guerre mondiale).

Il y a aussi *la drôle de guerre* qui désigne la période qui a précédé l'invasion allemande.

Comment: Même usage du générique "pendant la guerre" en Belgique, sans doute parce que les locuteurs actuels répètent encore un usage pris par leurs parents ou grands-parents qui ont vécu cette période ? En Belgique, on dit très souvent "la guerre 40-45" (ce qui m'a déjà valu des moqueries d'une connaissance française, sur un ton "m'enfin les Belges, vous savez même pas que la guerre a commencé en 39 partout dans le monde ?"). J'ai déjà lu "guerre 39-45" en France, mais à priori, cela me semble moins répandu (en France, j'entends) que l'usage belge équivalent. Quid du Québec ?

Comment: @Greg On dit bien ici "la guerre de 40" mais c'est vrai pas" la guerre 40-45".

Comment: Tant en France qu'en Belgique, on peut aussi trouver l'expression "L'an 40" pour évoquer le choc de l'invasion allemande, l'exode et le début de l'occupation.

Comment: @Greg Hmm, pas que je sache. L'an 40, c'est une année "qui n'existe pas", d'où l'expression: s'en moquer comme de l'an quarante, un peu comme la semaine des quatre jeudis.

Comment: Non, c'est bien une expression qui n'a rien à voir avec "s'en fiche comme de l'an 40" (expression qui est antérieure à 1940). J'ai déjà vu cette expression utilisée dans des ouvrages d'histoire "vulgarisée" ou romancée. Un exemple:  http://www.gallimard.fr/Catalogue/GALLIMARD/La-Suite-des-temps/Les-Francais-de-l-an-402

Comment: @Greg Ok, je ne la connaissait que comme l'an 40 de la République.

Comment: @Greg en revanche, on dit *C'est reparti comme en quarante !*